# Mocking cookie in cookie store with clj-http.fake?

Tags: unit-testing, cookies, clojure

I'm trying to figure out how to unit test a method that retrieves a cookie from a cookie store and stores it for further use.

```
(defn update-rb-session-id
  []
  (hiccup.util/with-base-url @rb-url
    (log/info "Updating RB session...")
    (let [url (hiccup.util/url "/api/review-requests/")
      cs (cookies/cookie-store)
      res (client/get (hiccup.util/to-str url)
                {:content-type :json
                 :cookie-store cs
                 :basic-auth [@rb-user @rb-password]
                 :as :json})]
      (log/info "response: " res)
      (log/info "cookie store: " (cookies/get-cookies cs))
      (let [sid (:value (get (cookies/get-cookies cs) "rbsessionid"))]
        (reset! rb-session-id sid)))))
```

My test looks like this

```
(facts "ReviewBoard"
 ((with-fake-routes-in-isolation {
   "https://my.reviewboard.com/api/review-requests/"
   (fn [request] {:status 200
                 :headers {
                           "content-type" "text/json"
                           "set-cookie" "rbsessionid=testsessionid;Path=/"}
                 :body "{\"review_requests\": []}"})}
  (with-redefs [slack-nag.reviewboard/rb-url (delay "https://my.reviewboard.com/")
              slack-nag.reviewboard/rb-user (delay "test-user")
              slack-nag.reviewboard/rb-password (delay "test-password")]
    (fact "it updates rb-session-id atom"
        (do
          (update-rb-session-id)
          (= rb-session-id "testsessionid")) => truthy)))))
```

Yet my `cookie-store` is empty even though I see the cookie being set in the handler function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The problem is that the cookie-store manipulation is being done inside [clj_http.core/request](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/master/src/clj_http/core.clj#L205) (by the underlying java libs) and what the clj-http.fake does is [replace that function](https://github.com/myfreeweb/clj-http-fake/blob/master/src/clj_http/fake.clj#L155) by the mocked version, so the java code that manipulates the cookie-store is never executed.

My suggestions would be:

1. the `res` should have a :cookies entry with a map with all the cookies, so just use that instead of creating and using an explicit cookie-store. Cookie store is used to make several requests to the same server without having to worry about setting the cookies in each subsequent request. From the example code, you don't seem to need the cookie-store.
2. If you really need a cookie-store, you will need to mock the behaviour of the java lib yourself. Probably a [custom middleware](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#custom-middleware-lists) to be set on your test will do the trick.